# Android Studio with Pantheon

Tags: pantheon, android-studio

Trying to choose a Linux Distro, would like to use Elementary OS with Pantheon desktop.  Can I run Android Studio in this environment?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

i recommend you to install it (and update it later when needed) through snapd

https://snapcraft.io/android-studio

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

then follow the website instructions

```
sudo snap install android-studio --channel
```

to update later

```
sudo snap refresh android-studio
```